# OleDB interpretting wrong row as header in XLS/XLSX files

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb

We have a page that interprets XLS, XLSX, and CSV files as datatables and uploads them to our database.

However occasionally users are unable to upload the file because it is interpreting the wrong row as the header. The most recent example it was interpreting the 178th row in the header. I tried saving it as a CSV so I could view it in notepad but couldn't find any special characters or anything going on in that row.

To have it uploaded properly I just need to copy and paste the data into another excel file or save it as CSV. But this is obviously not a step we want our users to take.

What could be happening here and how can we prevent this?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    Dim connstring As String
    If ext = ".XLSX" Then
        connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & infile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""
    ElseIf ext = ".XLS" Then
        connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & infile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Else
        connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & sFilePath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,);"""
    End If
    Dim olecon As OleDbConnection
    Dim olecomm As OleDbCommand

    Dim oleadpt As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
        olecon = New OleDbConnection
        olecon.ConnectionString = connstring
        olecomm = New OleDbCommand


        olecomm.Connection = olecon

        oleadpt = New OleDbDataAdapter(olecomm)
        ds = New DataSet
        olecon.Open()

        If ext = ".CSV" Then
            olecomm.CommandText = String.Format("Select * from [{0}]", sFilename)
        Else
            Dim sheetName As String = olecon.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")
            olecomm.CommandText = String.Format("Select * from [{0}]", sheetName)
        End If

        oleadpt.Fill(ds, "Sheet1")

        Dim dt As New DataTable("FileTable")
        dt = ds.Tables(0)

        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Trim()
        Next

        olecon.Close()
```

Comment: OLEDB to Excel is a PITA no matter how you do it.  Your code is assuming the first worksheet name in alphabetical sort order is the one you want.  That in itself is a big assumption unless you dictate a specific format.  If you can dictate a format, then why is the "Select" grabbing what ever it can find?  Are you familiar with the `Select * From [SheetName$A1:E]` format that tells it read from row1 in the specified columns through the UsedRange.LastRow?  This can help alleviate some the issues.

Comment: @TnTinMn we are dictating a specific format, however users aren't always that great at following that specific format. Since it's hard to interpret some of the errors, we'd like to make it work with things as close as possible and not have it break if there is something like an extra column. Using the format you mentioned seems to help get the right column header(in this case), however it appears to stop at column E. Is there a way to have it just grab the first row entirely to allow for extra columns?(A1:Z should work for most cases but maybe if there's something better)

Comment: I just ran a quick test on `[Sheet1$A1:Z]`  and it appears that the read columns are bound by the intersection of UsedRange and the specified columns, so specifying a high column letter may work.